# Help with Kohana 3 and a CRON

Tags: php, cron, kohana, kohana-3

I've set up a CRON to call a URL in Kohana 3.

```
php /home/user/public_html/index.php my/route/in/bootstrap.php
```

It seems to access the URL fine.

However, I have received this error (send back in an email that my host sends per CRON)

```
Undefined index:  HTTP_HOST
SYSPATH/classes/kohana/url.php [ 40 ]
```

[Source of url.php](http://github.com/kohana/core/blob/master/classes/kohana/url.php#L46)

Which is in a Kohana system file. Is this because the CRON job is not sending HTTP headers?

How would I fix this and get it to work (hopefully without hacking the core files).

Or am I doing the CRON wrong?

### Update

Pekka provided a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474106/help-with-kohana-3-and-a-cron/2474141#2474141), however I'd like to avoid changing the core files (though I will as a last resort).

It would seem Kohana 3 *does* have support for CLI, as there is a static property `$is_cli`.

http://github.com/kohana/core/blob/master/classes/kohana/core.php#L54

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you have `E_STRICT` notification turned on, and Kohana's error handling catches that. `E_STRICT` will complain about undefined indexes. The index is indeed undefined because there is no HTTP_HOST in a PHP script when called through the CLI.

Chances are your script is running fine despite this. You would have to turn down `error_reporting` at some point to prevent the message from showing up - I don't know Kohana well enough to know whether you can use a different config file when called from the CLI.

Maybe just turning down the `error_reporting()` in your specific controller does the trick, although it's a bit hacky.

Comment: It's weird I'd have to change this though, as it *seems* it has support for CLI (having a static property of the Kohana class `$is_cli`) http://github.com/kohana/core/blob/master/classes/kohana/core.php#L54 

I'm going to post to the Kohana forums as well. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: @alex it may be just an oversight. `E_STRICT` shouldn't fire at all in a production environment. (Of course, the much cleaner way would be to check for HTTP_HOST first.)

Comment: Actually I can turn off errors in the Kohana config. I just want to be able to test my CRON from here without turning errors off. I suppose I can just do that. Thanks Pekka.

Comment: @alex you're welcome. If you can influence the bootstrap, you can switch errors on/off depending on whether you're running in a cron job using php_sapi_name: http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.php-sapi-name.php

Answer (score 2):

As a general policy, I'd advise against just turning down error reporting levels to make errors go away.

The problem is that, as Pekka says, `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` isn't defined in CLI mode and the `Url` class needs this to when generating absolute URLs. This can happen in quite a few circumstances, for example when calling `URL::site` with `$protocol` set, or when using `Request::redirect()`, or when generating an RSS feed using the `Feed` helper.

What you need to do is to work out where in your CRONed controller you are trying to generate an absolute URL, and then decide whether you need to be. If you don't need it, then remove the offending code and it should run fine. If you *do*, then just turning off errors won't help you. Instead, add this to your `bootstrap.php` file:

```
if ( ! isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])
{
    $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = '<your-domain-here>';
}
```

You'll also need to make sure that you explicitly pass the protocol you want (presumably 'http') to `URL::base` rather than just passing `TRUE`. Otherwise it will use the current protocol which will be `cli://`.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to set the cron command like this:

wget --timeout=99999 -O/dev/null -q http://localhost/kohana/url/and/some/segment/or/whatever

Comment: I think if I do that though, then I can't test for `cli` in `PHP_SAPI` which means it could be accessed externally (unless I also check for host IP).